# OleDbCommand fails with "No value given for one or more required parameters"

Tags: vb.net, ado.net

I have error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

This is my source:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With
{
     .ConnectionString = "provider = Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; Data source = Database10.accdb"
}

Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand With
{
      .Connection = cn,
      .CommandText = "INSERT INTO NewData ([Nama], [Gaji], [Lembur/jam], [Tunjangan], [Potongan]) VALUES (@Nama,@Gaji,@Lembur/jam,@Tunjangan,@Potongan)"
}
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(New OleDb.OleDbParameter() _
{
    New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Nama"},
    New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Gaji"},
    New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Lembur/jam"},
    New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Tunjangan"},
    New OleDb.OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@Potongan"}
 }
 )

cmd.Parameters(0).Value = CStr(TextBox1.Text)
cmd.Parameters(1).Value = CStr(TextBox2.Text)
cmd.Parameters(2).Value = CStr(TextBox3.Text)
cmd.Parameters(2).Value = CStr(TextBox4.Text)
cmd.Parameters(2).Value = CStr(TextBox5.Text)
cn.Open()

Dim Affected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery

cmd.Parameters.Clear()

If Affected > 0 Then
   TextBox1.Text = TextBox3.Text
   TextBox2.Text = ""
   TextBox3.Text = ""
End If
End Using
End Using
End Sub
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Classic copy/paste error in cmd.parameters(n)

Comment: i have edit to 
 cmd.Parameters(0).Value = CStr(TextBox1.Text)
                cmd.Parameters(1).Value = CStr(TextBox2.Text)
                cmd.Parameters(2).Value = CStr(TextBox3.Text)
                cmd.Parameters(3).Value = CStr(TextBox4.Text)
                cmd.Parameters(4).Value = CStr(TextBox5.Text)
but still error

Comment: "@Lembur/jam" PERHAPS make it "@Lemburjam" for simplicity  Not a great column name there

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss thank you but now have new error "Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Comment: Be sure to match `,@Lembur/jam,` change to `,@Lemburjam,`, we cannot change the actual column name here but we can mitigate it a bit, note I still would consider changing the column name to NOT have slashes if you can, its just a bad idea in general

Comment: Note to be clear, if your actual column has slash you correctly used `[Lembur/jam]` and still must until/unless it is changed in the database itself and ALL other quires etc have changed as well.  Edit your question to remove/repair the copy/paste issue of multiple `cmd.Parameters(2)` to reflect your ACTUAL code in use.

Answer (score 0):

You use the `@...` syntax for parameters. That's `SqlDbCommand` syntax and won't work for your `OleDbCommand`. `OleDbCommand` parameters [use `?` placeholders](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO NewData ([Nama], [Gaji], ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)"
```

In that case, the `ParameterName` property is ignored.

---

In case anyone using `SqlDbCommand` reads this in the future: This is incorrect SqlDbCommmand code as well: `/` is not valid inside a parameter name. Thus, SQL Server reads `@Lembur/jam` as `@Lembur / jam`, i.e., the parameter `@Lembur` divided by (non-existant) column `jam`. In that case, the solution is to use a different name for the parameter, e.g. `@Lemburjam`. Note that the name of the parameter can be chosen freely and does not need to match the name of the field you are inserting.

Comment: If you read the connection string you'll see it's not SQL Server, it's ms-access. However, I suspect that the same problem exists there as well.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Good point, `OleDbCommand` actually uses a completely different parameter syntax. I have modified my answer.